# Mysql query IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.
One is where the price of ice cream is saved in different currency and another where which ice cream for the respective currency id is added by user to buy.

```
icecreamprice

id  icecream_id     name              currency_id   price
1       3        white_chocolate          2           3
2       3        white_chocolate          4           10
3       11       dark_chocolate           2            6
4       3        white_chocolate          3            4
```

Here id is pk and auto increment, icecream_id is being saved from a table where ice cream names and their respective id is mentioned.

```
cart

id  icecream_id  user_id   price_id(type=TEXT)
1       3           111     1,4
```

So i want to fetch everything from both icecreamprice and cart table when icecreamprice_id is present in cart_price_id and cart user_id is 111.

so this is my query

```
"SELECT id,icecream_id,name,price,c.user_id FROM icecreamprice ic,cart c WHERE c.user_id=111 and ic.id IN (c.price_id)"
```

But seems like this query is not effective, its fetching only one row insteam of two rows from first table

Comment: I think you should read about the first 3 normal forms - https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `IN` on a text string in MySQL, but you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead:

```
SELECT ic.id, ic.icecream_id, ic.name, ic.price, c.user_id 
FROM icecreamprice ic
JOIN cart c ON FIND_IN_SET(ic.id, c.price_id)
WHERE c.user_id=111
```

Output:

```
id  icecream_id name            price   user_id
1   3           white_chocolate 3       111
4   3           white_chocolate 4       111
```

Note that I have made your `JOIN` explicit and added the condition to the `JOIN` for clarity.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s4HHT46GbRTSFQBdwDD6a9/0)